# AngularJS: SetValidity in ng-repeat fields

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-form

I have a form that generates some fields using ng-repeat. I want to attach each independent field to set validity in case it is left empty. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ng-form` with your `ng-repeat`.  I'd update your example, but you didn't give me one... so the idea is something like this:

```
<form name="myForm">
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-form="repeatForm">
  <input type="text" name="foo" ng-model="item.foo" required/>
  <span ng-show="repeatForm.foo.$error.required">required</span>
</div>
</form>
```

If you needed to access 'setValidity' on the model for some reason, you'd probably have to pass `repeatForm.foo` to a function either on your controller or on your scope. like `ng-click="myWeirdValidationFunction(repeatForm.foo)"`. There's probably not much of a use case for this though.

Comment: But don't all items would have the same name? Therefore they are not independent of each other?

Comment: Even if they are of same name they are being scoped by the form repeatForm, so no issues with collision.